# How to add prefix to words between demarkers after encountering a certain pattern

Tags: unix, sed, scripting, prefix

I am new to `sed` and I am trying to figure out if it is possible to add a prefix to all words between two markers that are encountered after a string match in a line

suppose I have a line

```
abc xyz PAT1 { PAT2 PAT3 PAT4 } cdf fgd
```

`PAT1` is the string match and the markers being `{ and }` in this case

I want the result to be

```
abc xyz PAT1 { prefix_PAT2 _prefix_PAT3 prefix_PAT4 } cdf fgd
```

I can write a C code to do this, but I am new to scripting, so I was wondering if it is possible in `sed` ?

I know how to add prefix to certain columns of a line if a string is encountered
but `PAT2 PAT3 PAT4` can be any column and there may be more than 3 of them

Comment: In the sample result, `prefix_` is added to two of the words but `_prefix_` is added to the other.  Which prefix did you want?

Comment: _prefix was a typo . Sorry . It should be prefix_

Answer (score 1):

Consider this input file:

```
$ cat file
abc xyz      { PAT2 PAT3 PAT4 } cdf fgd
abc xyz PAT1 { PAT2 PAT3 PAT4 } cdf fgd
```

Using GNU sed:

```
$ sed ':a; s/\(PAT1.*{[^}\n]*\)\b\([[:alnum:]]\)/\1\n\2/; t a; s/\n/prefix_/g' file
abc xyz      { PAT2 PAT3 PAT4 } cdf fgd
abc xyz PAT1 { prefix_PAT2 prefix_PAT3 prefix_PAT4 } cdf fgd
```

#### How it works

- `:a`

  This defines a label `a`.
- `s/\(PAT1.*{[^}\n]*\)\b\([[:alnum:]]\)/\1\n\2/`

  This puts a newline in front of a word inside braces if `PAT1` precedes the braces.

  In more detail:

  - `\(PAT1.*{[^}\n]*\)`

    `PAT1.*{[^}\n]*` looks for `PAT1`, followed by anything, followed by `{`, followed by any characters other than `}` or newline.  The escaped parens that surround this expression, `\(PAT1.*{[^}\n]*\)`, cause whatever it matches to be saved as group 1, denoted as `\1`.
  - `\b`

    This matches a break between words.
  - `\([[:alnum:]]\)`

    This matches any alphanumeric character.  Because it follows a break between words, this character is the start of a new word.  (I allowed numbers to start a word. If this is not desired, change `alnum` to `alpha`.  Because it is surrounded by escaped parens, whatever this matches is saved as group 2, `\2`.

  Whatever is matched as above is replaced with `\1\n\2`, meaning the first group, a newline character, and the second group.  In sum, this puts a newline character in front of a word that occurs in braces following `PAT1`.
- `t a`

  If the above command did cause a substitution, then jump back to label `a`.  In other words, repeat the substitution until all words have a newline in front of them.
- `s/\n/prefix_/g`

  As a last step, replace newline characters with `prefix_`.

The newline is used here as a placeholder because we can be sure that it will never be in a line that sed reads. (Otherwise it wouldn't be a line.)

#### Non-GNU sed

The above uses `\b` to match a word boundary.  It also uses `\n` in substitutions.  GNU sed handles both of these well.  Other seds may or may not require some adjustment to the code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But does this take into account that the line has to have PAT1  ( pattern1 ) ?   . If it does not have PAT1 the prefix should not be added to the other words

Comment: @user2809853 OK.  I added a solution to the end of the answer that requires `PAT1` or else it won't make substitutions.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I would give you an upvote. But I am not yet allowed

Answer (score 1):

Input file contain:

```
abc xyz PAT1 { PAT2 PAT3 PAT4 } cdf fg
```

Try below code:

```
sed -i -e 's/PAT*/prefix_PAT/2g' filename
```

it will update your input file (filename)
output:

```
abc xyz PAT1 { prefix_PAT2 prefix_PAT3 prefix_PAT4 } cdf fgd
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer But I dont want the prefix on PAT1 .. PAT1 is for matching lines in which the prefix is to be added to words between the two markers